# Couldn't able to generate PDF from .docx using PHPWord

Tags: tcpdf, dompdf, mpdf, phpword, phpoffice

I'm using PDFWord for generating a dynamic document. The .docx and .html is generating perfectly but I'm not able to generate .pdf *(I've tried both DomPDF and TCPDF)*.

Here is my code sample:

```
// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('documents/RFP_for_'.str_replace(' ', '_', $info[org_name]).'.docx');

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('documents/RFP_for_'.$info[org_name].'.html');

// Saving the document as PDF file...
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath('vendor/tcpdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('TCPDF');

$template->saveAs('documents/'.$file_name.'.docx');
$temp = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('documents/'.$file_name.'.docx');
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($temp , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('documents/'.$file_name.'.pdf', TRUE);
```

Comment: THis needs way more detail - what happens? What error messages do you get? Is the pdf file created?

Comment: No! The HTML & DOCX has created but not the PDF. And it shows no error.

Comment: Does the library you are using have a method to show/catch errors?

Comment: No, I haven't show/catch error method